# A problem based on pigeonhole

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Numbers 1 to 1994 are divided into 6 sets.Show that at least in one  group there will be two numbers whose sum is also in that group ?

We can prove that at least one group will contain more than 332 elements.

A set is called sum free if it DOES NOT  CONTAIN sum of any two of its elements or does not contain twice of an element
If a set contains natural numbers from 1 to $2n+1$ its sum free subsequence will contain $n+1 $elements.Or in other word if we take the last half numbers $(\frac{n}{2} $ or $\frac{n+1}{2}$ according to number of elements of the set) it will be free.

But I cannot proceed further because my selection need not be consecutive numbers.

I have to prove that if a set contains more than 332 numbers it cannot be sum free..But How..?

Comment: Your definition of sum-free is incorrect. A set $S$ is sum-free if $S\cap (S+S)=\emptyset$, where $S+S=\{x+y:x,y\in S\}$.

Comment: A small note on English grammar: One says "It contains" or "It does not contain".  One does not say "It does not contains".  I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

This is from IMO 1978. The original problem is

An international society has members from six different countries. The list of members contains 1978 names, numbered 1, 2, . . . , 1978. Prove that there is at least one member whose number is the sum of the numbers of two members from his own country or twice as large as the number of one member from his own country.

Here is the solution from Arthur Engel's Problem Solving Strategies, which is where I first saw it

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Schur's theorem (one of many things called that, at least) states that partitioning $\{1, ..., n\}$ into $k$ subsets $S_1, \dots, S_k$ always has some $S_i$ not sum-free (i.e., there exist $x, y\in S_i$ with $x + y\in S_i$) if $n > k!\, e$. Since $6! e = 1927.16 < 1994$, your result follows.

Since this is a homework problem, I don't know how much combinatorics you've covered already and what tools are available to you; as such, I'd recommend you look up proofs of Schur's theorem if it hasn't been presented in class already and adapt the arguments to this case. (I don't know the proof offhand, but it seems to be amenable to standard Ramsey-style arguments. The value of $1994$ in the original problem is also suspiciously close to the bound from Schur's theorem.)

Comment: There's something weird. See how the theorem is stated here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchursProblem.html . Shouldn't $1994<6!e$ ?

Comment: Any partition of $\{1,..., n\}$ gives you a partition of $\{1, ...,m\}$ for $m < n$; if the latter is not sum-free, neither is the former. In other words: The larger $n$ gets, the harder it is to find the sum-free subsets. In that Mathworld article, $S(k)$ (switching their notation to mine) is the smallest value of $n$ for which a partition of $\{1, ..., n\}$ into $k$ subsets must contain a sum-free one.

Comment: I think you got $n$ and $m$ not in the right order. If I understand well, for $m<n$, if I know how to get a sum-free subset out of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$, I can reuse it to get one out of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, since partioning $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is partioning $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ as well. So your answer is valid indeed.

Comment: OK. I think there'a mistake here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchursProblem.html . It should be "Schur (1916) proved that no matter how the set of positive integers **more** than or equal to $\lfloor n!e\rfloor$  is partitioned into $n$ classes, one class is not sum-free." It got me **really** confused.

Comment: It's worded in a confusing way: They're trying to say that if you partition the set {1, ..., N} for N = $\lfloor{n! e}$ into $n$ subsets, then one of them must not be sum-free. Furthermore, the least $N$ for which the property above holds is the Schur number $S(n)$. (There's no mention of the idea that if the result holds for $N$, then it must holds for $N' > N$.) I'm not sure my rephrasing is any less confusing, but yeah, the Mathworld article was a bit tricky to parse.

Comment: Yes it's clear now, thank you. I wonder how OP was supposed to prove this all by himself...

Comment: One more thing: If you want to try to prove Schur's theorem directly, here's the trick to convert it to a Ramsey-style problem. Partition $\{1, \dots, n\}$ into sets $S_1, \dots, S_k$. Consider the complete graph on the vertices $\{1, \dots, n\}$, and give the edge between $x$ and $y$ the color $p\in \{1, \dots, k\}$ for $|x - y|\in S_p$ . Find, using Ramsey arguments, a monochromatic triangle $x < y < z$. Then $y - x$, $z - y$, and $z - x$ are in the same $S_p$, with $(y - x) + (z - y) = (z - x)$. Getting the bound down to $1994$ might require a bit of work, though.

Comment: @G.T.R.: I'm not sure either. Ramsey-style arguments would be my best guess, not knowing what sort of combinatorics class the OP is in, but getting reasonable bounds in those cases is pretty nasty.