# sum free sets and 4th schur number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am asked to prove:

"A set of integers $A$ is called sum-free if $a,b\in A \implies a+b \notin A$. Show that $\{1, 2, \ldots, 14 \}$ cannot be divided into three sum-free subsets."

Together with a sum-free partition of $\{1, 2, \ldots ,13 \}$, this is equivalent to $f(3)=13$, where $f$ denotes the Schur numbers. One valid partition is
$\{2, 3, 11, 12\}, \{5,6,8,9\}, \{1,4,7,10,13\}$. I am unsure how to prove the first part.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835000/390931) could be a useful way to think about the problem, although I think it only shows that any such partition of $\{1,\ldots, 14\}$ would have to consist of sets with 5, 5, and 4 elements.

Comment: neat observation